# JavaScript .scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"}); alternative is not working

Tags: jquery

The code has to be in my ajax call back i have tried the below and it didn't work has anyone got a solution to this for me please because my client once the transitions to be smooth but at the minute they are all choppy except in mozilla.

```
   success: function(data)         
 {
   if(jQuery( ".frequency" ).html(data)){
   //jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('#2010').offset().top }, 'slow');
  document.getElementById('dynamictabstrp').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});

 }

}
```

The alternative code i tried was the .animate but did nothing.

Comment: Only Firefox supports scrollIntoView with behavior "smooth" as you can see: http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollintoview

Comment: Yes i know this, i need an alternative but my alternative is not working.

Comment: Add the code to the question that you are having problem with or else it's impossible to know what might be wrong in that implementation.

Answer (score 12):

I'm from Argentina and I normally speak in Spanish, so, sorry for my English.

Here's the solution i've found in this website: https://blog.hospodarets.com/native_smooth_scrolling

### There say:

For **CSS** things are even more better. Just add one line of the code:

### **body{    scroll-behavior: smooth; }**

That code work with my site perfectly. To make this work you have to assign an  element with the value of the **href** attribute to an anchor point, for example: , in the other hand, you have to precise some point in your document that is the place you want to go after click on the link, for example: , make sure you write the appropiate attribute, that is **name**; in the value of this attribute you have to put the keywords you use in the link without the hashtag.

Besides, I'm looking information in the web that tell me how to change the time of the effect. I've tried by adding some values to the **scroll-behavior** property as **5s ease-out** like a example in the web, but it didn't work for me.

Hope I contribute with your work, have a nice day.

Lucas J. Guerra P.

Comment: Just working on Firefox. So it's not a proper solution.

Comment: Man, great answer! Nowadays this works pretty well because browsers consortium.

Comment: In my case I had to add `{ scroll-behavior: smooth; }` to the `html` tag instead of `body` tag